# hibernate SQL Server

Tags: hibernate, web-applications

If I want to make a web-application using hibernate (the java framework), what languages can I  use to do so ?

Comment: hm . assuming i do a java web application using hibernate between that and my mssql database. What is hibernate's role ?

Comment: NH is an OR/M it let you persist and retrieve objects from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hibernate you'll need to use Java or Groovy. 
You can use Spring ROO or Grails (web application frameworks) to help you create your app.

If you don't want to use Java or Groovy, there are many alternatives for Hibernate written in other languages.

Comment: hm ok so if i understand, if i chose to do (for example) java web application using hibernate, i don't need to "write code" for hibernate, i only need to make the xml configuration files and the hbm.xml for each java clasS?

Comment: You'll need to write your Java classes that represent the database tables (unless you are using Spring ROO which does it for you). You don't have to write XML files as Hibernate has annotations that can be used inside the Java code (you'll only need to configure hibernate - db properties etc.)